# UWP API BLE 'just works' pairing method without bonding

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal, pairing

I need to pair with BLE device using 'just works' pairing method without bonding. I tried custom pairing PairAsync method with DevicePairingKinds.ConfirmOnly and  DevicePairingProtectionLevel.Encryption and every time Windows reports succesful pairing result with ProtectionLevelUsed == DevicePairingProtectionLevel.None. But actually BLE device rejects pairing because windows BLE stack every time requested bonding. How to avoid bonding request using win10 uwp api?

Comment: Hi @denny, have you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: @Ilia, Nope, still no solution. :C